# fill month gaps

Tags: mysql, database, date

I need to fill the gap with 0 if no order occurred in a month.

table example:

```
date         product
2010-02-01   20 
2010-03-01   10
2010-03-01   30
2010-06-01   15
```

My basic query is:

```
SELECT date,SUM(orders.product) AS product
FROM orders 
GROUP BY month(date),YEAR(date)
```

That would return:

```
date         product
2010-02-01   20 
2010-03-01   40
2010-06-01   15
```

but I need:

```
date         product
2010-02-01   20 
2010-03-01   40
2010-04-01   0
2010-05-01   0
2010-06-01   15
```

I made a table with all the possible dates:

```
datefield
2010-01-01  
2010-02-01  
2010-03-01 
2010-04-01  
2010-05-01  
2010-06-01  
2010-07-01  
etc...
```

But when I try to join the two it doesn't work. (edit: Only works on the first missing month.)

```
SELECT calendar.datefield AS DATE,
IFNULL(SUM(orders.product),0) AS product
FROM orders RIGHT JOIN calendar ON (MONTH(orders.date) = MONTH(calendar.datefield)) AND (YEAR(orders.date) = YEAR(calendar.datefield)) 
WHERE (calendar.datefield BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(DATE(date)) FROM orders) AND (SELECT MAX(DATE(date)) FROM orders))
GROUP BY DATE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ON (DATE(orders.date) = calendar.datefield)
```

You are extracting the year/month/day out of `orders.date` but not from datefield. It may be that.

I would try

```
ON (DATE(orders.date) = DATE(calendar.datefield))
```

Also, as you want months, I would check only by months

```
ON (MONTH(orders.date) = MONTH(calendar.datefield)) AND (YEAR(orders.date) = YEAR(calendar.datefield))
```

And now you only need a row for month, instead of a row per day.

Answer (score 0):

You need to union your calendar table.

```
SELECT date,SUM(orders.product) AS product
FROM orders 
GROUP BY month(date),YEAR(date)
union
select datefield AS date, '0' AS product
from calendar
```

Answer (score 0):

In my calendar table, the date is held in the column "cal_date". Syntax is for PostgreSQL; it should be easily adaptable to MySQL.

```
select to_char(cal_date, 'YYYY-MM') as period, sum(coalesce(product, 0))
from orders 
right join calendar c on c.cal_date = orders.date
where (
  cal_date >= (select min(date) from orders) and
  cal_date <= (select max(date) from orders)
)
group by period
order by period
```

`to_char(cal_date, 'YYYY-MM') as period` returns a column named "period", containing values like "2010-02". When I'm aggregating by month, I don't like to return a date. It tends to confuse people.

The right join should be based on the date values, not on just month and year. (Think about it for a minute.)

The WHERE clause will misbehave if the first month or the last month in your range of interest has no orders. Basing the range on passed parameters rather than actual orders is probably a better idea.